# GWT - setStyle on gwt-MenuBarPopup (multiple popup)?

Tags: gwt

I have several MenuBar in the same page, and I want to apply a specific style to each one. Applying different styles to MenuBarPopup is my problem here.

With an instance of the popup, i could call the `addStyleName()` method. I can get one with the `MenuBar.addCloseHandler(CloseHandler<PopupPanel> handler)` method,  but I can't find a way to retrieve the instance when the popup is displayed.

Comment: Alternatively you can set different classes (or html id's) on the different menubars, and then define in CSS different styles for pop-ups that belong to each menubar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way:

The default style applied to the popup is `MenuBar.getPrimaryStyleName() + "Popup"`

So using a `MenuBar.addStyleName("myStyle")` won't affect the popup, but `MenuBar.setStyleName("myStyle")` will.